# I can not add a loop to another Python loop, please help me

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-loops

I want to add another loop to a Python loop that I have, but I can not come up with the solution, I am new to Python so I need help to make it work, please.

Here is what the code does:

1- It starts with the first CSV file, which reads from the first row (there is a given range to use).

2- it uses the data to run the function. After a few seconds of delay, it goes to the next row and does the same, same process to use all rows in the given range.

3- After a few seconds of delay, it goes to the next CSV file, does the same process as above (delay between each row), until all CSV files are used.

The problem is, when I run the file for the second time and more, it uses the same rows.

I want to add another loop to it, so when I run it again, it iterates over the next row that has not been used.

This is how it should work, assuming the given range is: 2 rows.

1- the first-time run, should read **rows 1 and 2** of all CSV files, use the data to run the function.

2- second-time run,  should read **rows 3 and 4**  of all CSV files, use the data to run function. and so on when the next time the file is going to be run.

I appreciate if I can help to make this work,
I have posted this problem some time ago but I did not get any working solution. so I try again.

Here is code that works:

```
from abc.zzz  import xyz
path_id_map = [
    {'path':'file1.csv', 'id': '12345678'},
    {'path':'file2.csv', 'id': '44556677'}
    {'path':'file3.csv', 'id': '33377799'}
    {'path':'file4.csv', 'id': '66221144'}]
s_id = None

for pair in path_id_map:
    with open(pair['path'], 'r') as f:
        next(f)  # skip first header line
        for _ in range(1, 3):      
            line = next(f)
            img_url, title_1, desc_1, link_1 = map(str.strip, line.split(';'))
            zzz.func1(img_url=img_url, title_1=title_1, desc_1=desc_1, 
                      link_1=link_1, B_id=B_id=pair['id'], s_id=s_id)
            time.sleep(25)
```

CSV file content looks like this:

```
img_url,desc_1 title_1,link_1
site.com/image22.jpg;someTitle;description1;site1.com
site.com/image32.jpg;someTitle;description2;site2.com
site.com/image44.jpg;someTitle;description3;site3.com
```

thanks.

**Edited:**

OK, I got some help with a posted solution, but unfortunately, it did not work, and the person did not want to continue to work on the provided code to solve the problem.

I am back to asking for help again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put your processing logic in a separate function and call that?

All files should have same size or you need to put safety checks to not process when next(f) return empty. **(which is a good thing to have anyway)**

```
def process_n_lines_from_offset(file_set, processed, offset):
    for pair in path_id_map:
        with open(pair['path'], 'r') as f:
            next(f)  # skip first header line

            # skip processed lines
            x=0      
            while (x<processed):
                next(f)
                x += 1

            num_processed = 0
            for _ in range(offset):      
                line = next(f)
                img_url, title_1, desc_1, link_1 = map(str.strip, line.split(';'))
                zzz.func1(img_url=img_url, title_1=title_1, desc_1=desc_1, 
                          link_1=link_1, B_id=B_id=pair['id'], s_id=s_id)
                time.sleep(25)

                num_processed += 1
    return num_processed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = 0
    default_offset = 2
    num_processed = process_n_lines_from_offset(path_id_map, start, default_offset)
    num_processed = process_n_lines_from_offset(path_id_map, num_processed, default_offset)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried the code, at first I did not get any error, it did work for the first row of data, but then it stopped, and gave an error on this line: ```num_processed += 1``` and the error is : ```UnboundLocalError: local variable 'num_processed' referenced before assignment```

Comment: declare num_processed=0 before 'for _ in range(offset)'

Comment: OK, thanks for the reply,  I don't get that error or any other error, but the problem is it uses the same rows of CSV files when run for the second time, my first run, it did use row 1 and row 2, the second run use row 1 and row 2 again, instead of reading row 3 and row 4, I don't understand how this code suppose to remember the last row it has been used.

Comment: What is happening in 'skip processed lines' section?
Add x += 1 in the loop, so it just itereates over the lines it has already processed in the last run.

Comment: thanks for the correction, but it still has the same problem, it just added another problem to it as well,  you see now for the first run, it uses row 1 and row 2 of all CSV files and then go and starts from the first CSV file again and read row 3 and 4 and do the same for rest of CSV file, then it stops, when I run the file for the second time, it starts from row 1 and row 2 again.

Comment: Can you answer following question please:
1. The first call of process_n_lines_from_offset processes all files correctly (2 lines from each file)?

Comment: Since SO has put a link here to move discussion to chat, I woul end the discussion from my side. The approach however is:
1. The defined function process_n_lines_from_offset process N lines of all files in a single call and returns the number of lines  processed of the last file.
2. Use that return value to call the function again.
3. The function skips the 'processed' lines from each file and then starts processing 'offset' number of lines.

Good luck and have a nice day!